# Ignore blank text box

Tags: vb.net

I made a project to select data from  my database by vb.net 
I have 1 text box, 2 comboboxes and 2 date fields to 
I want to make an and operation in the search 
I generated the code, but it didn't work as required
It works only if I entered values in all the 5 field 
If any field left blank, the code considered it a value and it doesn't show any data
I want to make the and operation and If i left one of the fields
blank, the system ignores it in the code

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim x1 As String
    Dim x2 As String
    Dim x3 As String
    Dim x4 As Date
    Dim x5 As Date
    x1 = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
    x2 = CStr(ComboBox1.Text)
    x3 = CStr(ComboBox2.Text)
    x4 = DateTimePicker1.Value
    x5 = DateTimePicker2.Value

    UtilizationTableAdapter.Fill(WINCC_DATADataSet.Utilization, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)

End Sub
```

for the fill code in the table adapter, it is like this

```
SELECT ID, Cast_number, Stoppage, Downtime, Departement, Reason, Note, Eventtime
FROM     Utilization
WHERE  (Cast_number = @Cast_number) and (Stoppage = @Stoppage) and (Departement = @Departement) and (Eventtime > @Eventtime) AND (Eventtime < @Eventtime1)
```

Comment: Which parameter comes from which control? You'll have to provide more clear details for us to be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your SQL to ignore null input, e.g.

```sql
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE (@Column1 IS NULL OR Column1 = @Column1)
AND (@Column2 IS NULL OR Column2 = @Column2)
```

You then write your VB code to pass null values where appropriate.  Using straight ADO.NET, that means use `DBNull.Value`.  With a typed `DataSet`, it means using `Nothing`:

```
x1 = If(TextBox1.TextLength = 0, CStr(Nothing), TextBox1.Text)
x2 = If(ComboBox1.SelectedItem Is Nothing, CStr(Nothing), ComboBox1.Text)
x3 = If(ComboBox2.SelectedItem Is Nothing, CStr(Nothing), ComboBox2.Text)
x4 = DateTimePicker1.Value
x5 = DateTimePicker2.Value

UtilizationTableAdapter.Fill(WINCC_DATADataSet.Utilization, x1, x2, x3, x4, x5)
```

I've ignored the fact that you were assigning an `Integer` to the `x1` variable, which is declared as type `String`, which makes no sense.  If the `Fill` method expects an `Integer` then your variable should be `Integer` and if it expects a `String` then why convert the `String` you already have to an `Integer` and then back again?

Comment: Thanks alot for your support, x2 and x3 work fine , but if i left x1 blank or null, the code doesn't work, yea this field is string

Comment: You're going to need to be more specific than "the code dopesn't work". That is NEVER an acceptable description. You need to specify EXACTLY what the code does do and EXACTLY how that differs from your expectation. Also, you need to have debugged your code so that you understand exactly what is happening in the code when it executes, not just what the user sees. If you haven't set breakpoints, stepped through the code and examined the state of your variables, etc, as it executes then you don't know what's happening so you can comment on what's happening sufficiently.